# How to get the length of vessels from the photo in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to get the length of the vessels from the image below (I'm interested in a region selected in blue):
[image]
Due to uneven lighting, I'm working on an image with a flat-field correction:
I3 = imflatfield(I2,20);
[image]
I tried using kmeans with 3 levels and got a pretty nice mask, however after skeletonization with bwskel or bwmorph I get a very confusing and complicated web of segments.
[image]
[image]
[image]
How to get only the main segemnts of the vessels without all of these additional small loops? Probably I should work on a mask but none of the bwmorph options make me closer to the result that I want.

I tried working with a mask and some of the bwmorph options like a bridge, fill, and thicken, but they did not result in better skeletonization.

EDIT: I'm uploading an original image. Just to be clear I'm interested mostly in microvessels seen near white disk (visible after zooming in on the photo).[image]

Comment: please provide a clean input image, without that tinted circle over the data you're actually interested in. people need something to experiment against. -- first, remove that white disk, either physically or digitally (remove from mask for following operations). then apply *less* severe highpass (that's not flatfield correction) because you do need some lighting equalization but not so much that large vessels disappear. then you need to work with segmentation based on color (hue, saturation, value/lightness), to compare against your results on the grayscale data.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question but I give you a least some guidance. Your problem is 2D image data analysis, which is a very complex and wide field - where I have some experience (enough to tell you that there is no silver bullet for your problem, this is going to be serious effort, like months of work).

- the actual problem at hand is unclear. There are vessels of all sizes on the image, from larger ones to tiny ones. You have to decide what matters and where you want to put a threshold. This is a research question and has nothing to do with coding.
- one issue is that the contrast of your input image is limited, which will also limit any result
- your approaches are a good start, but I doubt this is going to be enough. I suggest at least the following two to three steps:

1. reduce the "high-frequency noise", focus on larger/bulk features. Use 2D FFT forward+back transformation. There are good example of this you easily find.
2. focus on "edge detection". There are excellent and very powerful algorithms for edge detection that you also easily find yourself.
3. for a real application, I would in the end chose a "fit-based method". I would start with a super-simple few straight-line model and perform a numerical regression/optimization. This requires a lot of fine-tuning, will never be 100% reliable, but will in most cases give perfect results. Actually, I would choose a super-robust and simple genetic-algorithm solver for this task.

In the end, what you need is serious consultancy, which we could discuss too, or supervision+guidance of other experts. But this is beyond stack overflow.